# How to Efficiently Do Retry and Delay for an API Call without Using sleep()

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to know a good way to do a retry and delay when calling an API endpoint without using `sleep()`

So, in my code, I want to call a GET from an API endpoint and check the returned result. If the result is valid, I continue. If it is not, I would like to wait for a period of time and try to call GET again and check for the result again up to a certain attempt.

```py
result = api.get()
attempt = 1
while not valid(result) and attempt != 10:
    sleep(10) # I do not want to use it because I think it is not good. I would like to use something like Event based, but there is not event here.
    result = api.get()
    attempt += 1
```